# Why is time $1\ \mathrm{s}$? Is this a default?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I am quite new to physics and am still wrapping my head around some of the core concepts. I have a homework question that states:

> A 115-kg astronaut is floating at rest relative to her spacecraft in
>   deep space. She throws an 18-kg tool kit at 4.6 m/s away from the
>   spacecraft. Show that the astronaut will recoil at a speed of 0.72 m/s.

So I understand that we need to show that $v_F\text{ (final velocity)} = 0.72\ \mathrm{m/s}$ and that we can find $v_F$  from $v_F = \frac{\text{Force}}{\text{Mass}}\times\text{Time} + v_0\text{ (initial velocity)}$.

So
$$F = ma = 18 \times 4.6\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}} = 82.8\ \mathrm{N}$$
From here we can find
$$0.72 = \frac{82.8}{115}\times 1 + 0$$

What I don't understand is why is time 1? For the answer to equal 0.72 time must equal 1s but why? How do we know that the amount of time she applied the force to this this toolbox was 1 second or is this some kind of a default?

Comment: 4.6 m/s is not an acceleration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, you have taken the wrong approach to this problem. The fact that you were able to calculate a time of one second is purely a coincidence; actually, that time has nothing to do with the problem.

The equation you have in mind, which I would suggest writing
$$v_f = a\Delta t + v_0$$
involves the initial velocity $v_0$, final velocity $v_f$, and acceleration $a$ of a single object, as well as the length of time $\Delta t$ for which the object accelerated to get from its initial velocity to its final velocity. You need to know three of these quantities in order to use the equation to find the fourth one. In the problem you've been given, you only have two: initial velocity and final velocity of the astronaut, as well as of the ship. You do not know the acceleration of the astronaut, nor the length of time she spent accelerating, so you do not have enough information to use this equation.

To solve the problem, I'd suggest taking a look at the quantities you *do* have, and find an equation that better matches that information.

Comment: I have been reading and think I have it. Third law states equal and opposite reaction. If she pushed the tool box at 82.8N then she too would be pushed back by 82.8N which given her weight would 82.8N/97kg = 0.72m/s

Comment: Even your calculation of 82.8 N is invalid. The acceleration you used, 4.6 m/s/s, does not appear anywhere in the problem. Perhaps you misread the speed of 4.6 m/s as an acceleration?

Comment: AH HA MOMENTUM! Change in momentum is M = m*v which is 18*4.2 = 82.8kgm/s then you do the newtons third law to show and get her change in momentum which is also 82.8 and then you can calculate her velocity which is M/m or 82.8/115 = 0.72m/s

Comment: Thank you for your patience with this. I thought that if an object was static and then suddenly traveling at 4.6m/s it must have accelerated by 4.6m/s/s, I see now that was wrong and that is why we could not use that calculation.

Comment: Yep, that's how the learning process goes! Good to hear you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You have an interesting mixture of errors which happened by luck to have produced the correct answer.

> $v_F$  from $v_F = \frac{\text{Force}}{\text{Mass}}\times\text{Time} +
> > v_0\text{ (initial velocity)}$

Is in fact a perfectly valid equation which can be seen if it is rearranged as

$\rm force \times time = mass \times \text{final velocity} - mass \times \text{initial velocity}$

This is telling you that the impulse is equal to the change in momentum.

In this problem the impulse on one the astronaut due to the tool kit is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to the impulse on the tool kit due to the astronaut.

So the change of momentum of the astronaut is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to that of the tool kit.

Rather than set it out this way it is often stated that for a system on which no external forces act momentum is conserved.

Assuming that the initial momentum of the astronaut and the tool kit are zero we can write

$m_{\rm astro}v_{\rm astro,initial}+m_{\rm kit}v_{\rm kit,initial}=0=m_{\rm astro}v_{\rm astro,final}+m_{\rm kit}v_{\rm kit,final}$ from which you can solve your problem.

However if this equation is rearranged we get

$m_{\rm astro}v_{\rm astro,final}-m_{\rm astro}v_{\rm astro,initial}=-(m_{\rm kit}v_{\rm kit,final}-m_{\rm kit}v_{\rm kit,initial})$

which is

$\rm impulse_{\text{on astronaut due to kit}}=-\rm impulse_{\text{on kit due to astronaut}}$

---

So in the end for your impulse you assumed a time of one second and a constant force which was not necessary to solve the problem.
All that was required were the statements that there were no external forces and the impulses on the astronaut and the tool kit were equal and opposite.

Answer (score 0):

AH HA MOMENTUM! Change in momentum is M = m*v which is 18*4.2 = 82.8kgm/s then you do the newtons third law to show and get her change in momentum which is also 82.8 and then you can calculate her velocity which is M/m or 82.8/115 = 0.72m/s